# Showing transformation linearity for a 2x2?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following transformation linear? If so, is it an isomorphism?

T(M) = $\begin{bmatrix}2&4\\6&12\end{bmatrix}$M from $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$

I know that to show transformation linearity - we show that it is closed under addition and multiplication - but I am unsure of how to do it using transformations of this form (also a 2x2). Could anyone show me how to get started?

Also - would it be correct that this is not an isomorphism since the matrix is not invertible? (determinant equals 0).

Comment: You have to prove that $T(M_1+M_2)=T(M_1)+T(M_2)$ for any matrices $M_1,M_2\in\mathcal{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$. Try to write down that each of the two sides of the equality means in your case, and you will realize that they are evidently equal. On the other hand, you are right. $T$ is not an isomorphism because the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4\\ 6 & 12\end{bmatrix}$ is not invertible. However, the argument have to be more especific. Try to show that $T$ is not surjective (for instance, is it possible to find $M$ such that $T(M)=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$? )

Comment: For the isomorphism part, recall that the determinant is multiplicative, i.e. $det(AB)=det(A)det(B)$ so the determinant of $T(M)$ can only ever be $0$ so is not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Proving its linearity is rather simple. Denote the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2&4\\6&12\end{bmatrix}$ as $A$. Then we have:
$$T(M_1 + M_2) = A(M_1 + M_2) = AM_1 + AM_2 = T(M_1) + T(M_2)$$
The proof for scalar multiplication is simple by properties of matrix arithmetic. Meanwhile, if you want to show this transformation is an isomorphism, consider the solutions to $T(\vec{M}) = 0$ and write the solution as column vectors. Then the question degrades into solving $$\begin{bmatrix}Am_1 & Am_2\end{bmatrix} = 0$$
Notice that $A$ is not invertible though, so this has non-trivial solutions, thus it is NOT injective. Thus it cannot be surjective

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication is linear: additivity is simply distributivity of addition w.r.t. multiplication in the *ring* of $2\times2$ matrices (more generally, $n\times n$ matrices), and compatibilty with scalar multiplication comes from the $\mathbf R$-algebra structure of this ring.